# Example for distributions that are not normal but have equal mean

Tags: r, distributions, mean

I want to simulate data from distributions that are not normal but have equal mean give mean example for these distributions

For example, I have this example for non-normal distributions but have different means

```
set. Seed(1234)
a<-matrix(rlnorm(30*100, 0,2),100)
b<-matrix(rcauchy(30*100,1,1),100)
c<-matrix(rt(30*100,4),100)
```

I want to change these different means to equal means especially 0.

Answer (score 7):

1. Cauchy distributions don't have a mean. (For distributions with a mean, just subtract their population mean from the random variable, and you have a new random variable with population mean 0.)

   Note that Wikipedia gives the mean (along with many other pieces of information) for many distributions in common use. Any distribution you have the means to generate (that has a mean), you can shift the mean to 0, or indeed to any other desired value. For some distributions, it's no longer of the type you started with; e.g. if you start with an ordinary two-parameter Weibull and shift it, it's not an ordinary two-parameter Weibull any more, but a shifted-Weibull.
2. If you meant that you want them to have the same *sample* mean rather than the mean of the distribution (as you appear to be asking), you can just subtract the sample mean from each data set. You can also add back any constant mean you like to them once they all have sample mean 0, so any other mean is just as easy.

   However, you no longer have a random sample from the given distribution, since you induce dependence between the observations by forcing them to obey the constraint (the values will necessarily sum to a constant). You have to choose between getting the exact sample mean you want and having independent identically distributed values from some population distribution; you can't have both.

   If you wanted them to have the same sample mean and standard deviation, you can subtract each sample's own mean and then divide by the sample standard deviation. In R this is easily achieved via a call to `scale`.

Answer (score 1):

I second @glen_b's suggestion to look at the information on the mean (and other things) on Wikipedia (or other sources).  With that information you can find/construct distributions with a chosen mean, without shifting.

For example, the mean of the gamma distribution is the shape parameter times the scale parameter (or the shape divided by the rate).  So choosing 2 sets of values with the same product (quotient) will give the same mean, but have different shapes (and variances) when generating from gammas.

Here is some R code examples with simulation mean of 6:

```
> x1 <- rgamma(10000, shape=3, scale=2)
> x2 <- rgamma(10000, shape=2, scale=3)
> c(mean(x1), mean(x2))
[1] 5.996801 5.982464
> plot(density(x1), type='l')
> lines(density(x2), col='blue')
> x3 <- rgamma(10000, shape=6, scale=1)
> x4 <- rgamma(10000, shape=1, scale=6)
> mean(x3)
[1] 6.004391
> mean(x4)
[1] 5.958392
> lines(density(x3), col='red')
> lines(density(x4), col='green')
```

There are other distributions that you could do the same thing with (but the gamma is nice and simple), or you could even use this information to generate data from different distributions (e.g. a lognormal and a Weibull) but choose the parameters to get the same mean.

Answer (score -1):

Just define the distribution according to the shift picking your two favorite distributions.

For instance, take $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.3)$ then pick your favorite $\mu$ and set up $U = X - 0.5 + \mu$ and $V = Y - 0.3 + \mu$. Boom $E[U] = E[V]$.